# Glamourisation/Glamorisation/Glamorization?

Tags: verbs, orthography

I ran into a problem whilst writing the word 'glamourisation'. I want to adhere to the British spelling, which I think would be with  and  but the Oxford English Dictionary has no entry for 'glamourisation' but does has one for 'glamorization' and it's super confusing.

Is the  just me hypercorrecting? What would be considered correct in British English?

Comment: Please include the sentence where the word would be used. It could be that "glamour", which is a noun, is sufficient by itself. The verb form is spelled *glamourise (glamorize)*

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm using it in a title, as in "the glamourisation of the human mind", does that help?

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your spelling. You can find a good many examples of "glamourisation" from UK news websites.

Comment: Lexico (Oxford) has under UK English [glamorization](https://www.lexico.com/definition/glamorization?locale=en) (also glamourization) which definitely seems strange. I think removing "e" and putting "ation" on the end of an existing "-ise" verb is the normal way, even if a lot of these zation/sation words aren't in the dictionary. Maybe someone who understands more about lexicography can explain - it might just be a case of what forms they've seen used.

Comment: Yeah I've been checking Google hits - "Glamourisation" has the least number of hits. It could be that the word is derived from US English which is why the 'z' is there - and then maybe UK English after a while changed it to 's'? That's what seems to have happened when I look at the Oxford English Dictionary.